# How to Use Python Code from GitHub in Zapier to Pull Data from a Website and Format it for a Google Sheet Using "Get by Zapier" & "Code by Zapier"

Tags: python, zapier

******Disclaimer: I am not a coder...I've tried researching how to do this on my own, but I'm too far out of my wheelhouse to figure it out. So, I'm hoping someone can show me how to use the Python actions inside of Zapier to automate a repetitive task.******

The Goal:

I want to be able to pull the data of "new move-ins" to the area from my [church's website](https://lcr.churchofjesuschrist.org/?lang=eng) (name, address, phone, etc) and have it put into a Google Sheet, so I can keep track of efforts to welcome them.
I know how to set up everything in the Zap, except for the Python actions that pull the data from the site and then formats it the way I need it for the spreadsheet.

Someone has already coded a way to pull the info I want using Python, and posted it on GitHub here:
https://githubhelp.com/SpencerMKSmith/LCR-API

It says:
To Install, Run:

```
pip3 install lcr-api
```

Usage:

```
from lcr import API as LCR

lcr = LCR("<LDS USERNAME>", "<LDS PASSWORD>", <UNIT NUMBER>)

months = 5
move_ins = lcr.members_moved_in(months)

for member in move_ins:
    print("{}: {}".format(member['spokenName'], member['textAddress']))
```

This is the church [website](https://lcr.churchofjesuschrist.org/?lang=eng), and this is the specific [move-in report](https://lcr.churchofjesuschrist.org/report/members-moved-in?lang=eng) I want to pull from--both of which are password protected (my login info gives me access).

The current Zap configuration I am using is:
"Schedule by Zapier" > "Get by Zapier" > "Code by Zapier (Run Python)" > "Google Sheets"

The problem is that, as I said, I am not a coder, so I am at a loss as to how I should be implementing the code from GitHub within Zapier to get the result I want.

I have tried putting different combinations of the GitHub code into the "Get by Zapier" and "Code by Zapier" actions, but I always just get:
["Syntax Error in Code" & "No Data in Mapped Fields"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tovj.png)

For reference, this is what the data looks like on the original site:
[Members Moved-In Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SunI1.png)

I'd like to pull all of the info points from the site (name, age, move in date, household position, gender, address, phone) into their own columns in the Google Sheet--as it is all potentially useful when welcoming people to the area.

My question is how do I structure the "Get by Zapier" and "Code by Zapier" actions to get that result?

I welcome any questions and appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is relevant:

```
You cannot require external libraries, or install or import libraries commonly referred to as "npm modules". Only the standard node.js library and the fetch package are available in the Code by Zapier app. fetch is already included in the namespace.
```

Link: https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/use-javascript-code-in-zaps#limitations-with-code-steps

Perhaps the solution is to create a quick function on something like Heroku and then make a GET or POST to it?

If more help is needed, I would highly recommend connecting with a Zapier Expert that may be able to help custom build this: https://zapier.com/experts.